# Getting variable by name in C#

Tags: c#, variables, resolve

Is there a way to get the value of a variable just by knowing the name of it, like this:

```
double temp = (double)MyClass.GetValue("VariableName");
```

When I normally would access the variable like this

```
double temp = MyClass.VariableName;
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what context you would need to do this, where accessing a value as a property normally would not suffice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). For example if `PropertyName` is a public [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) on `MyClass` and you have an instance of this class you could:

```
MyClass myClassInstance = ...
double temp = (double)typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(myClassInstance, null);
```

If it's a public [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx):

```
MyClass myClassInstance = ...
double temp = (double)typeof(MyClass).GetField("FieldName").GetValue(myClassInstance);
```

Of course you should be aware that reflection doesn't come free of cost. There could be a performance penalty compared to direct property/field access.

Comment: Be careful; it might be very slow using this frequently.

Comment: Would reflection be slower then a 10 case switch filter?

Comment: @Andeas, no freaking idea, I bet 5 bucks reflection would be slower but the best would be to measure it in order to be sure and you'd better be *sure* before putting some code in production.

Comment: @Andreas: I bet. A 10 case switch filter is about as slow as a 3 case switch filter.

Comment: @Andreas: Just chiming in with what others are saying here. I had a project where I replaced a reflection-based solution with a switch/case and got more than an order of magnitude speedup in several tight loops.  For more complex scenarios, it's also worth trying a delegate wrapping a lambda that just fetches the property -- those also can beat reflection by an order of magnitude or more.

Comment: @Andreas: pretty sure a switch would be significantly faster. Switches are converted to a bunch of sequential if statements if the number of cases is six or less, anything more and it get's converted into a static dictionary.