# Get Enum from its name. Is this possible?

Tags: c#

I have the enum:

```
public enum Colors { Yellow, Red }
```

Then I have a string:

```
String enumName = "Colors";
```

Is it possible to get an enum instance from the enumName? Something like:

```
Enum colors = // get enum with name "Colors".
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Do you want the `System.Type` object that represents your enum type?

Comment: You can get one of the values of an enum by using Enum.TryParse. What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically I have the name of an enum in a string, for example "colors", and a value, for example "Red", and I need to know if Red is part of that enum.

Comment: Do you know what assembly (C# project) the enum will be defined in? Do you know what namespace it will be in?

Comment: No. I only have the name of the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Stuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string enumName = "Colors";
            string value = "Red";


            var loadedPublicTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetExportedTypes());
            var possibleEnums = loadedPublicTypes.Where(x => x.IsEnum && x.Name == enumName);

            foreach (var e in possibleEnums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is{1} a member of {2}", value, Enum.GetNames(e).Contains(value) ? "" : " not", e.FullName);
            }

        }


    }
    public enum Colors
    {
        Red,
        Yellow
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `Enum.IsDefined(e, value)`, that's a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic type and find a variable by name, but you would have to have an instance of all the enums you want to include in your search.

Check out the following post: [Getting variable by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053521/getting-variable-by-name-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

You need the full name of the enumeration type (e.g. `System.Drawing.KnownColor, System.Drawing`, or `Microsoft.MediaCenter.UI.Colors, Microsoft.MediaCenter.UI`).

Once you have this, you can use reflection to create an instance of the corresponding enum.

Comment: Question is unclear, but with reflection anything is possible. He could search all types in some assembly (assemblies) to find those whose name *without* the namespace part is `"Colors"`.