# Accessing constants using string variable

Tags: c#

I'm working on Unity, using C#, and I made up a script that would make my life simpler if I could access constants using string variables.

```
public class Foo
{
    public const string FooConst = "Foo!";
    public const string BarConst = "Bar!";
    public const string BazConst = "Baz!";
}

// ...inside some method, somewhere else
public string Bar(string constName)
{
    // is it possible to do something like this?
    // perhaps with reflections?
    return Foo.GetConstant(constName);
}
```

My only solution was to create a method that gets the constant inside a `switch`. But every time I add a new constant, I have to modify that `switch`.

Fun fact: I'm a PHP kid that moved into C#. I like it is pretty strict, strong-typed and stuff... but that also makes things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Either name your constant-Variable like the constant-string -or- use a dictionary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting variable by name in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053521/getting-variable-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you describe a problem, you're solving? You can do what you need with a help of reflection, but it's very strange construction for static-typed language.

Comment: @walther that question asks how to get a property, not a constant. In that solution, you require an instance. In this case, I suppose I don't need an instance since I'm trying to access constants.

Comment: Well, it's usually a bad idea either way. Static typing ensures you don't try to access things that don't exist, that you try to work with right variables and types etc. You try to avoid that and rely on string names instead. You should rethink your architecture, because php is very bad in that regard. Dump the things you've learned during php period and focus on how to develop software with C# the right way. Don't try to do the same things, because it will usually end up badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly do that using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx), but IMHO a better option would be to store the constants in a dictionary or some other data structure. Like so:

```
public static class Foo
{
    private static Dictionary<string,string> m_Constants = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    static Foo()
    {
        m_Constants["Foo"] = "Hello";
        // etc
    }

    public static string GetConstant( string key )
    {
        return m_Constants[key];
    }
}

public string Bar( string constName )
{
    return Foo.GetConstant( constName );
}
```

Obviously this is a simplification. And it would throw an exception if you pass a key that doesn't exists etc.

Comment: My bad. I just looked at my code and I have used dictionaries already. The thing is that I have an enum so I could do this "myDict[MyEnum.SomeProp]". But I receive the name of the enum constant as string (string name = "SomeProp"). So my question was actually, How to get enum out of string? Uh, I should create a new Q. Although the other A's answered correctly (and I learned things), yours led to the right way.

Comment: @renocor `Enum.Parse`

Answer (score 2):

This uses reflection:

```
var value = typeof ( Foo ).GetFields().First( f => f.Name == "FooConst" ).GetRawConstantValue();
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution. I would just use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`. When you use `First` and the field does not exists, it throws an exception, with `FirstOrDefault` you get a `null` value, if the field is not present!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use Reflection. Like this:

```
public string Bar(string constName)
{
    Type t = typeof(Foo);
    return t.GetField(constName).GetValue(null));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try in this way with reflection

```
var constExample= typeof(Foo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static |
               BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
    .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && fi.Name==constName).FirstOrFefault();
```

where `constName` is the constant that you are looking for

Refere [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Reflection.FieldInfo_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation about property of FieldInfo.

As you can see I have filtered for `IsLiteral` = true and `IsInitOnly` = false

- `IsLiteral`:

> Gets a value indicating whether the value is written at compile time
>   and cannot be changed.

- `IsInitOnly`:

> Gets a value indicating whether the field can only be set in the body
>   of the constructor.