# How to increase object name in a loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops, object, names

I have 1600 textboxes.I want something like this :

```
Textbox1.Text="1"
Textbox2.Text="2"
Textbox3.Text="3"
Textbox4.Text="4"
...
```

I know that doesn't work but I need a loop like this:

```
For i as integer = 0 to 1600  
(textbox+i).text=i  
Next
```

I couldn't find anything about this.I don't know is this possible.Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you use arrays?

Comment: 1600 textboxes?? Is this WinForms?

Comment: Of course it is a solution for this example.But I mean "increasing object names in a loop" is possible.Focus this,don't care the example.

Comment: Ric.It's an example.Can I do it ?

Comment: I have to ask... why do you have 1600 text boxes.. ?

Comment: I used "1600" for getting attention.If I have 4 textboxes,trying to use a loop  isn't useful right ?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdkb.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
For i as integer = 0 to 1600  
   CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" + i.ToString()), TextBox).Text = i.ToString()
Next
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Cast your i to a string, @newbieProgrammer. Also, you can skip a step by jumping directly to the assignment like so: `CType(Me.Controls("Textbox"+(i).ToString()), TextBox).Text = (i).ToString()`. Nearly there.

Comment: "&" fixes syntax error but there is a runtime error on "text1.text = i " : NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Comment: Your null reference exception is probably because the loop starts a 0 instead of 1

Comment: The problem is that there may not be a textbox with the name text0 or text1 for example. this code does not provide you with error handling.

Comment: that will look for 1601 textboxes

Comment: change the Me to the object of the form containing the textboxes.

Comment: Yeah,changed 0 to 1 and it works.Thank you all,this code works !

Comment: @Ric: This is simply a piece to show the process of looping through 1600 (1601 in this case!) text fields. I'm sure the OP could figure out which numbers he needs to set the `Text` attribute for. The OP also specifies a seemingly linear set of controls (TextBox1, TextBox2 ... etc).  Error handling may be sledgehammer and nut domain for this simple demo.

Comment: @Paul lol yeah I get it, I just do the error handling without thinking about it tbh.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop from a predefined range of values, then this should do the trick:

```
For i = 1 to 1600
    Dim txt As TextBox = TryCast(Me.Controls("TextBox" & i.ToString), TextBox)
    If txt IsNot Nothing
        txt.Text = i.ToString()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Doesn't Find return an array?

Comment: Error : Argument not specified for parameter 'searchAllChildren' of 'Public Function Find(key As String, searchAllChildren As Boolean) As System.Windows.Forms.Control()'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's enumerate all of the textboxes:

```
var textboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                             .ToArray();
```

Now that we have our textboxes, let's iterate over them and set their number:

```
for(int i = 0; i < textboxes.Count(); i++)
{
  var textbox = textboxes[i];
  textbox.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This will iterate over the controls many times.  If you so `.Select((c,i)=>new {Control=c,Index=i})` then `foreach` over the collection you will get the index value and only interate the collection once.

Comment: Each call to `.Count()` may interate the set again.  You are better off using the `.Length` or better still setting a variable to the count before the `for` or using `foreach`

Comment: You are correct that it would iterate over the collection of controls multiple times, but the `ToArray()` call would evaluate the LINQ statements. Each call to `Count()` wouldn't iterate the set again. That extension method checks to see if the enumerable is an array or a list. If I would've chosen a `List<T`, the `Count()` and `Length` properties would've been different. Just because this is a less efficient approach doesn't mean that it's not a solution.

Comment: I didn't vote you down.  I just said there are much better ways to do it.  It will still loop the list twice in your example.  (You may have gotten a vote down because they asked for VB.Net and you responsed in c#)

Comment: Ah.. That makes sense. I have an internal VB to C# converter in my head. I actually didn't even notice until you had mentioned it.

Comment: I have to admit that it makes little sense to create a new array when the objects are already in one; bit of a waste of memory, especially when you can refer directly to the named object and cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option (although I don't recommend it - it's slow!!!!) you could use `Reflection` to get them by name in a loop.

e.g:

```
For tb As Integer = 1 To 1600
    Dim textBox As TextBox = GetTextBoxByReflection("TextBox" & tb.ToString())
    textBox.Text = tb.ToString()
Next
```

See also [Getting variable by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053521/getting-variable-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Please don't post C# as a proposed answer on a question tagged VB.NET

Comment: Reflection is surely a very slow way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop all controls...

```
    Dim tb As TextBox
    For Each ctrl As Control In form1.Controls
        If ctrl.GetType.ToString = GetType(TextBox).ToString Then
            tb = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
            tb.Text = ctrl.ID.Substring(7)
        End If
    Next
```