# How can I replace the parameters in my request url using C#?

Tags: c#, rest, string-interpolation, string.format

I have n number of request urls, like below

```
https://{user.id}/{user.name}/testing1
https://{user.number}/{user.name}/testing1
https://{user.age}/{user.height}/testing1
https://{user.gender}/{user.name}/testing1
https://{user.height}/{user.age}/testing1
https://{user.weight}/{user.number}/testing1
```

I have the below test data class which has n number of values.

```
public class User{
public string id = "123";
public string name = "456";
public string age = "789";
public string gender = "1478";
public string height = "5454";
public string weight = "54547";
public string number = "88722";
.......
.......
.......
}
```

And I need to make the url

```
https://{user.number}/{user.name}/testing1 into 
https://{88722}/{456}/testing1
```

In my code, I will be randomly getting a request url(from a json file) and i need to replace the parameters with the values given in the class. Can this be done? If yes please help. Thanks

I have tried using string.format() - but it doesnot work, because I am randomly getting the url and I am not sure which value needs to be replaced.
I also tried using the interpolation, but found not helpful either unless i can do something like

```
User user = new User();
string requesturl = GetRequestJSON(filepath);

//The requesurl variable will have a value like 
//"https://{user.id}/{user.name}/testing1";

string afterreplacing = $+requesturl;
```

Update: After some more googling, I found out that my question is very much similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288857/string-interpolation-with-variable-content-in-c-sharp). I can use the first answer's alternate option 2 as a temporary solution.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053521/getting-variable-by-name-in-c-sharp

Comment: can't you do like string requesturl = string.format("https://{0}/{1}/testing1" ,user.id ,user.name);

Comment: You aren't using string interpolation in your code. `$+requesturl` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am clearly missing the point (and lets assume all the values are in when you do new user(); )

You just want

```
User user = new User();
string requesturl = $"https://{user.id}/{user.name}/testing1";
```

then all the variables like {user.id} are replaced with values. such as "https://88722/456/testing1"  if you need the {} in there you can add extra {{ to go with such as

```
 string requesturl = $"https://{{{user.id}}}/{{{user.name}}}/testing1";
```

Comment: I am reading the request URL from a JSON file. And i have tried the code you have given . My issue is I am not able to use $ sign infront of a string variable - like $+requesturl to do the interpolation. so something like string replaced = $+GetrequesturlfromJSON();

Comment: Well.. that then was an important part to explain, as thats not what your code shows.. we can on,y solve the problems presented not make up what you actually meant

Comment: Then my answer still stands, on how to do the URL at least..    While you have updated the question you havent demonstrated what you now seem to be wanting to do.. you've still left the code you want to sort doing non compilable and asking in effect the same question.

Comment: I have updated the codes as well. I would like to interpolate the string (requesturl) i receive.Like the below code.I now know that it is an incorrect syntax. 

          string afterreplacing = $+requesturl;